# Python-docx ,Error when trying to set a table cell sytle as 'toc 2'

Tags: python, styles, cell, docx, python-docx

I am new to python-docx module.

What i have is a table which is already in the document.

I want table to have some features so i made it by hand and add 1 row as
i wish (first column is for numbering ,its style is "toc 2").

What i am trying to do is ,first set text to first row (done!),
then copy the first row and change the text with other datas.

I have managed to copy and change the data in new rows
but i can't add numbering style to them.
i have a line of code like:

`new_row.cell[0].paragraph[0].add_run(" ").style('toc 2')`

And i have tried to set text first then change the style like:

`new_row.cell[0].paragraph[0].add_run(" ")
new_row.cell[0].paragraph[0].style = document.styles['toc 2']`

But both are giving me the same error:

`CT_Tbl object has no attribute part`

Any suggestions?

NOTE: i am creating new_row with this function:

`def insert_row(table,index):
    new_row = table.add_row()
    table.rows._tbl.insert(index , new_row._tr)
    return new_row`

NOTE2: Tracecall:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\ws\docx_projects\automation.py", line 351, in tablo_doldur
        cell_text = new_row_cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run("").style('toc 2')
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\text\run.py" ,line 132 ,in style
        return self.part.get_style(style_id , WD_STYLE_TYPE_CHARACTER)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\shared.py" ,line 250 ,in part
        return self._parent.part
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\shared.py" ,line 250 ,in part
        return self._parent.part
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\shared.py" ,line 250 ,in part
        return self._parent.part
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\docx\shared.py" ,line 250 ,in part
        return self._parent.part
AttributeError: 'CT_Tbl' object has no attribute 'part'
```

Comment: Please add the full stack trace from when the error occurs so we can see precisely which calls led to the error.

Comment: Okay, this line of code is weird: `cell_text = new_row_cells[0].paragraphs[0].add_run("").style('toc 2')`. Best if you break these up I think so you don't have long chains of return values to keep straight. Here, `style` is a property, not a function, so having `style('toc 2')` is not valid. But it seems to be choking before it gets there, on the `Run.style` property call. I'd isolate that run and then have a look at it's `.parent` object type and so on to see what the parent chain looks like. Probably best to add this as an issue to the GitHub issue list so we can work through it step by step

Comment: Alright i will try as you said and add an issue as well.
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Had to done it with win32com module. Made a macro in word that when selected a table's first cell restarts numbering at 1. Then i run the macro from my script to apply it all tables.
it works now but its very slow.